# Creating Function with Generic Return Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, types

Currently i am having following function

```
  public int GetVariableValue(TaxReturn taxReturnObj, string identityKey)
    {
        int returnTypeOut = 0;
        if (taxReturnObj.Identity.ContainsKey(identityKey))
        {
            int.TryParse(taxReturnObj.Identity[identityKey], out returnTypeOut);
        }
        return returnTypeOut;
    }
```

To retrieve the value we are using following code,

e.g.

```
int valPayStatus = GetVariableValue(objTaxretrun, TaxReturnIdentity.aadata_identity_paystatus)
```

It was working fine untill now as All the **Identity** Values were Integer,but recently we have added New Identites with String and Boolean types.
So i want to make the above function as **Generic**...but i don't know how to go about that,I tried to search on google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `I tried to search on google but couldn't find anything` did google died?!..checking...aah everything is ok and it can find things like [this](http://blog.kjeldby.dk/2009/06/using-generic-methods-and-constrains/)

Comment: I'd go with different methods: GetVariableValueAsInt, GetVariableValueAsString, ... The problem here is that you're going to do specific treatment for each type (int.parse, bool.parse, simple cast to string...), so some types will be left out. By calling a generic method GetVariableValue<T>, I have no way to know what types are accepted for T and what types will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public T GetVariableValue<T>(TaxReturn taxReturnObj, string identityKey) 
    { 
        if (taxReturnObj.Identity.ContainsKey(identityKey)) 
        { 
            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(taxReturnObj.Identity[identityKey], typeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
           return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much...with little changes..worked perfectly..:)

Answer (score 5):

I would do this, maybe there's a better way;

```
public T GetVariableValue<T>(TaxReturn taxReturnObj, string identityKey)
        {
            if (taxReturnObj.Identity.ContainsKey(identityKey))
            {
                if(typeof(T) == Int32)
                {     
                    int returnTypeOut = 0;
                    int.TryParse(taxReturnObj.Identity[identityKey], out returnTypeOut);
                    return returnTypeOut;
                }
                else if (typeof(T) == System.String)
                {
                //code here
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
```

And you could call it like this

```
int valPayStatus = GetVariableValue<int>(objTaxretrun, TaxReturnIdentity.aadata_identity_paystatus)


string valPayStatusStr = GetVariableValue<string>(objTaxretrun, TaxReturnIdentity.aadata_identity_paystatus)
```

Comment: Thanks for help...But problem here is i cannot return directly cause i am using int.parse method which requires output parameter...and that output parameter needs to be initialized first..and thats the place where i am getting compilation error...

Answer (score 1):

```
public T GetVariableValue<T>(TaxReturn taxReturnObj, string identityKey)
{
    if (taxReturnObj.Identity.ContainsKey(identityKey))
    {
        return (T)taxReturnObj.Identity[identityKey];
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Something like this ?
Doesnt mean it wont throw an an execption if you pass it the wrong type tho.

Comment: I would do this to, but maybe surrounding it with a try-catch

Comment: Thank you very much,I am getting compile time error like Cannot cast expresssion of type string to type T

Comment: I wondered if you ints were actually strings if you need to parse the value use something like renes code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
public T GetVariableValue<T>(TaxReturn taxReturnObj, string identityKey)
{
    if (taxReturnObj.Identity.ContainsKey(identityKey))
    {
        return taxReturnObj.Identity[identityKey];   
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

if you find the `key` in your dictionary `Identity` then return that particular value, without parsing it, or you may return the `default` value

Comment: Why would this work? I don't think it's possible to implicit convert object to T. I'm guessing the Identity-property is a list of objects.

Comment: well from `ContainsKey`, Identity looks like a dictionary, may be defined as `public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Identity { get; set; }`

Comment: And it may be `public Dictionary<string, object> Identity { get; set; }`